# Printing from shotwell slow

Tags: printing, shotwell

When opening a an image in shotwell, if I tell it to print, it take s a very ling time (3-4 minutes sometimes) before the printer will actually receive and print the image.
Open the same image using GIMP, send to same printer, prints almost immediately.

It is like it is not sending some sort of termination or job complete signal and waiting to time out.

While waiting on it to print, other items submitted to print will queue and print after it finishes, and if I instruct a second print from shotwell, the second hangs for the same time, so it seems to be isolated specifically to this viewer.

I can easily and reliably recreate this, I just am not sure where to start determining why it is happening.

Comment: I would suggest starting here?: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems ... If you are using cups and maybe add some more info? Could be a bug if its reproducible in the same environment. What version of ubuntu, shotwell, cups is being used? Or it could be fixed upstream?

Comment: 14.04 Ubuntu, Shotwell 0.18.0, has existed since last two major updates in my ubuntu. x64. CUPS prints instantly, but still have this issue DELL 3115cn MFP but does the same with the Ricoh network printer at my office.